# Webcomic that has a probably minor character girl that writes fanfiction just about minor characters

Tags: identification-request

I read some fiction on the internet that had a minor character girl who talked aloud to someone about how they flesh out the backstories of *really* minor characters, like the ones that say [Welcome To Corneria](https://tvtropes.org/Main/WelcomeToCorneria), in the fanfiction that they write, with the implication that they've written a lot of fanfiction.

I *think* it was a webcomic in a cartoony / anime style, and that I would've read it a few, 2-3, years ago, but I reread archives frequently enough that it probably won't help.

I looked through TVTropes' list on their [Most Fanfic Writers Are Girls](https://tvtropes.org/Main/MostFanficWritersAreGirls) and no character rings a bell, at least.